I want to move the tasks to another page completely
I have a daily tasks project and I created two pages in it: home.dart and completed_task.dart. When I click on any task, it is transferred to the completed tasks pages, but it remains on the Home page. I want to move it completely to the completed tasks so that it disappears from the home page if it is complete.
home.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:project_todo_list/widget/todo_item.dart';

import '../model/todo.dart';
import '/applocale/applocale.dart';
import 'completed_task.dart';


class localization extends StatelessWidget {
  const localization({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        AppLocale.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale("en", "EN"),
        Locale("ar", "AR"),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final todosList = ToDo.todoList();
  List<ToDo> _foundToDo = [];
  final _todoController = TextEditingController();
  int id = 0;
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _foundToDo = todosList;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: _buildAppBar(),
      body: _buildBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    prefixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(
                      maxHeight: 20,
                      minWidth: 25,
                    ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: "${getLang(context, "Search")}",
                    hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 50,
                        bottom: 20,
                      ),
                      child: Text("${getLang(context, "Title")}",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    for (ToDo todoo in _foundToDo.reversed)
                      ToDoItem(
                        todo: todoo,
                        onToDoChanged: _handleToDoChange,
                        onDeleteItem: _deleteToDoItem,
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 20, right: 20, left: 20),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: const [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                        blurRadius: 10.0,
                        spreadRadius: 0.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _todoController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "${getLang(context, "AddItem")}",
                        border: InputBorder.none
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, right: 20),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _addToDoItem(_todoController.text);
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    minimumSize: const Size(60, 60),
                    elevation: 10,
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    '+',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 40,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _moveToCompletedTasks(ToDo todo) {
    setState(() {
      todo.isDone = true;
    });
  }

  void _handleToDoChange(ToDo todo) {
    setState(() {
      todo.isDone = !todo.isDone;
      if (todo.isDone) {
        _moveToCompletedTasks(todo);
      }
    });
  }

  void _deleteToDoItem(int id) {
    setState(() {
      todosList.removeWhere((item) => item.id == id);
    });
  }

  void _addToDoItem(String toDo) {
    setState(() {
      todosList.add(ToDo(
        id: id += 1,
        todoText: toDo,
        created_at: DateTime.now().toString(),
      ));
    });
    _todoController.clear();
  }

  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<ToDo> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      results = todosList.where((item) => !item.isDone).toList();
    } else {
      results = todosList
          .where((item) =>
      item.todoText!
          .toLowerCase()
          .contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()) &&
          !item.isDone)
          .toList();
    }
    setState(() {
      _foundToDo = results;
    });
  }

  AppBar _buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      elevation: 0,
      title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/man.png'),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => CompletedTasksScreen(
                        completedTasks: todosList.where((todo) => todo.isDone).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.history),
              ),
            )
          ]),
    );
  }
}

completed_task.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '../applocale/applocale.dart';
import '../model/todo.dart';

class localization extends StatelessWidget {
  const localization({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        AppLocale.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale("en", "EN"),
        Locale("ar", "AR"),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CompletedTasksScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<ToDo> completedTasks;

  const CompletedTasksScreen({super.key, required this.completedTasks});

  @override
  State<CompletedTasksScreen> createState() => _CompletedTasksScreenState();
}

class _CompletedTasksScreenState extends State<CompletedTasksScreen> {
  final todosList = ToDo.todoList();



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      appBar: _buildAppBar(),
      body: _buildBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Stack(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
                  child: Text("${getLang(context, "CompletedTask")}",
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 60,
            bottom: 20,
          ),
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: widget.completedTasks.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final todo = widget.completedTasks[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  todo.todoText!,
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd - h:mm a').format(DateTime.parse(todo.created_at!)),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
    ]);
  }

  AppBar _buildAppBar() {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      elevation: 0,
      title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/man.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}

todo_item.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:project_todo_list/applocale/applocale.dart';
import '../model/todo.dart';

class localization extends StatelessWidget {
  const localization({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        AppLocale.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale("en", "EN"),
        Locale("ar", "AR"),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ToDoItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final ToDo todo;
  final Function(ToDo) onToDoChanged;
  final Function(int) onDeleteItem;
  const ToDoItem ({super.key, required this.todo, required this.onToDoChanged, required this.onDeleteItem});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
      child: ListTile(
          onTap: () {
            onToDoChanged(todo);
          },
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
        tileColor: Colors.white,
        leading: Icon(
          todo.isDone? Icons.check_box : Icons.check_box_outline_blank,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        title: Text(
          todo.todoText!,
          style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        subtitle: Text(
          DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd - h:mm a').format(DateTime.parse(todo.created_at!)),
        ),
        trailing: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
          height: 35,
          width: 35,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          ),
          child: IconButton(
            color: Colors.white,
            iconSize: 18,
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () {
              onDeleteItem(todo.id);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

todo.dart
class ToDo {
  int id;
  String? todoText;
  String? created_at;
  bool isDone;

  ToDo({
    required this.id,
    required this.todoText,
    required this.created_at,
    this.isDone = false,
  });

  static List<ToDo> todoList() {
    return [

    ];
  }
}

I tried in more than one way, but to no avail. What is the correct solution?
